# comparing efficient methods to get nearby GeoPoints or GeoLocations in a database

Tags: android, sql, database, geolocation, geospatial

comparing efficient methods to get nearby GeoPoints or GeoLocations in a database.

Let's say I have over one million Geo points of users with respective Latitude and Longitude stored in a database stored in decimal form. I wish to know if these two methods are similarly efficient to get nearby locations of users within a given radius considering that I have so many Geo Points stored.

Method 1:
I've read that I can use a spatial database but have never used one. (Will I be able to perform CRUD operations conveniently?)

Method 2:
(This is what I'm hoping to do since I've never used a spatial database)
I wish to use a nosql database to store over a million Latitude and Longitude of different users in decimals.

Then get the Bounding circle or rectangle around a given location and then query the database for GeoPoints within the bounding circles. [Please refer to this.](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html)!

And then calculate and sort the Geopoints by distance from the Center Geopoint.

Also Good to Know: I'm trying to develop an android app like uber or other taxi services that allows a user to get location of cabs nearby. Right now I wish to store the all user locations in a database and get nearby users with either of the methods above. If there is a better way to do this please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: A dedicated geospatial db (or db extension) will likely be more performant than a vanilla NoSQL solution - they'd have specialized indices, plus built-in functions for common use cases (like distance-from-point, which is _very_ different for a sphere).  Most of the major RDBMS vendors provide solutions/extensions for this.  There _may_ be something in the NoSQL space too, but I'm not aware of anything at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know the distance from point for a sphere differs. I'm researching the geospatial extension on mysql. I hope that works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tags are quite off-topic, as the database will most likely be on a server rather than in the app.

Postgresql allows you to build indexes on coordinates that are optimised for lookups based on distance from a given point. Other variables may allow the same. Other databases may allow the same as well. That's very simple and very efficient.

Otherwise you can indeed cut your space into squares and look into the right square (and neighbouring ones in most cases) to avoid going through the whole database each time. A bit more work, and not as efficient. The whole difficulty is in finding the right size for the squares (or rectangles).